# Exclude zero-padded regions from network loss - Keras 2.0 Theno Backend (segmentation network)

Tags: keras, padding, theano, loss

I'm training a segmentation network in Keras with Theano backend and I'm using ImageDataGenerator with flow_from_directory.

My images have flexible size. In order to use flow_from_directory though you have to specify a fixed size (target_size) and while reading the images, the function automatically fills the points outside the boundaries of the original image.

Currently I'm setting this specified size a value larger than my largest image- say may largest image is 300x400, I fix the target_size to 400x400 and use fill_mode='constant' and cval=0 to pad the points outside original image with zero.

Now my problem is as follows. During training, I do not wish these padded regions to contribute to my loss function at all. Does anyone has an idea how to do that?

Comment: have you liiked into masking ?

Answer (score 1):

[Masking](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) could help you.

> Masks a sequence by using a mask value to skip timesteps.
>
> For each timestep in the input tensor (dimension #1 in the tensor), if all values in the input tensor at that timestep are equal to mask_value, then the timestep will be masked (skipped) in all downstream layers (as long as they support masking).
>
> If any downstream layer does not support masking yet receives such an input mask, an exception will be raised.

It's technically made for time series, but it should work for images too with some tweaking. [Here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/411) you can find some attempts to do so (and some alternatives).

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. I checked it out, though still there is no working example on the net for using masking in non-lstm structures.

Comment: Well if Masking ISN'T support by a layer, Keras throws an exception, as stated in the docs. So you should be able to apply to any layer that supports it theoretically? I'd be actually interested to know if you manage, keep me updated!